# Redundancy of information and algorithm to do lossless decompositions

Tags: dependencies

> Let be a relation `R(NameFile, Size, Directory, DateCreation,HourCreation,Login,AutAccess,DateAccess,TypeAcces`
>
> ```
> F={NF,D→S;
>    NF, D →DC;
>    NF, D→HC;
>    L,NF,D→A;
>    L,NF,D,DA,HA→TA;
> }
> ```
>
> Part of the instances are given in the following array:
>
> [image: Example]

- Does the relation create information redundancy?
- What would a decomposition of R without loss of information and without loss of dependency be?

I don't think so because it seems that the information given by the dependencies seem to be unique.

I know there is algorithm to decompose R without loss of information or without loss of dependency but I don't know them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the relation create information redundancy?

Yes, for instance you have the information on the file (name, size, data creation, etc.) repeated for different accesses to the same file.

> What would a decomposition of R without loss of information and without loss of dependency be?

The following decomposition is both in Third Normal Form and in Boyce-Codd Normal Form and is without loss of data and loss of dependencies. It can be obtained by applying both the “analysis algorithm” to produce the BCNF, and the “synthesis algorithm” to produce the 3NF, but note that in general only the latter is guaranteed to avoid any loss of dependencies:

```
R1 < (D DC HC NF S),
{ D NF → DC
D NF → HC
D NF → S } >

R2 < (A D L NF),
{ D L NF → A } >

R3 < (D DA HA L NF TA),
{ D DA HA L NF → TA } >
```

Any good database book will describe both the algorithms.

Comment: I don't perfectly understand why do I have information on the file repeated for different accesses of the same file, what are accesses? Are they `NF,D→S;
   NF, D →DC;
   NF, D→HC;` because here `Size`, `DateCreation`, `HourCreation` are only created once.

Comment: You have files uniquely identified by Name and Directory (NF, D), that have Size, DataCreation, HourCreation (S, DC, HC) has property (this dependes on (NF,D). Then different persons (Login, L), can access to those files with a certain Autorization (A) (and each login for each file has a certain authorization (NF, D, L) → A. Finally, when a user access a file, in a certain Hour and Day (HA, DA), perform this access with a certain type (TA), so that (L,NF,D,DA,HA→TA). This is a lot of redundancy!!!

Comment: You can see that in the decomposition, there is a relation to represent only files (R1), one to represent the information for file, user and his/her access rights for that file (R2), and finally a relation for storing the accesses of the users to the files (R3).

Comment: Haaa, okay, I think I see it. It is because we shouldn’t need such informations such as `NF,D` to determine `A` and should only have `L` for instance? Same thing with `TA` which should have only be defined by `DA,HA`?

Comment: Login has several access rights for different files, so it is necessary the relation R2, in order to know wich right has for a certain file. In the same way you should know the file that has been accessed, and the login, otherwise the information about the TA, DA, and HA is simply unuseful. Consider if you can give a unique id to a file, let's call it `FID` (file id), then the first relation could be `R1(FID D DC HC NF S)`, the second `R2(FID, L, A)`, and the third `R3(FID L DA HA TA)`.